# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec unable to catch all output

Tags: java

My shell script **run.sh**

```
echo "Running my.r"
Rscript /opt/myproject/my.r
```

Output of **run.sh** from command line

```
Running my.r
2019-06-14 job starts at 2019-06-13 16:52:21
========================================================================
1. Load parameters from csv files.
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: automation.engine ... %>% -> eval -> eval -> read.csv -> read.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/...../_nodes.csv': No such file or directory
```

However my Java program can only capture the first line "Running my.r". How can I catch every single line of the output? Below is my Java code:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/opt/myproject/run.sh");
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    proc.getInputStream()));
            try {
                proc.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }
            while (read.ready()) {
                String line = new String(read.readLine());
                results += "\r\n" + line;
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are only capturing standard output from `Process#getInputStream` (like `System.out`) and errors are printed in error stream (`System.err`). You will have to capture `Process#getErrorStream()` as well.

Instead of `Runtime.exec()` you can use `ProcessBuilder` and then invoke `redirectErrorStream` on it to merge those 2 streams.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream()

Comment: Yes it is the getErrorStream. Thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: Also note that if you wait for the process to finish before reading, the process may deadlock if it outputs more than the system's pipe buffer size (e.g. 65k on Linux).